Can I make Explorer restore previously open folders in Windows 11 on restart?
Under Windows 10 it was possible to make Explorer restore previously open folders after a system restart (albeit with a registry hack, if I remember correctly). This facility seems to have gone with Windows 11, even though there is now a proper option "Restore previous folder windows at logon" in the settings. It would seem that this is to do with the introduction of tabs in Explorer.
This article suggests that the problem has been fixed in 23H2 (my version), but it doesn't work for me - I tried setting "Restore previous folder windows at logon" in the settings, but oddly this seemed to restore two of the three folders, but in separate instances of Explorer.
I also tried turning on "Automatically save my restartable apps and restart them when I sign back in" under "Sign In Options" in the Accounts section of settings as suggested in this article - this restored all three folders, but again in separate Explorer instances, rather than as the original tabs in a single instance.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
